# sqlite-net запись в определенное поле (c#)

Tags: c#, sqlite

В проекте используется БД *SQLite*, для работы с ней используется библиотека *sqlite-net*.
Таблица имеет вид:

```
id | tag | text
```

Первое поле - автоинкрементный `id`, второе - текстовое поле, заполненное, третье поле - тоже текстовое, пустое.

Задача: в определенном месте (по соответствующему `id` или `tag`) осуществить запись в поле `text`.

Можно ли это вообще реализовать с помощью *sqlite-net*?
Или все же нужно прибегать к использованию запросов? Если только так, то какой будет запрос?
PS:
вот класс для работы с таблицей, метод `AddData` просто добавляет запись в конец таблицы в поле `text`.

```
public class data
{
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string tag { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }

        public data AddData (string Text)
        {
           //string dbPath;
           //string dbPath = Path.Combine(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "products.db");
           //dbPath = @" data source=C:/data.db; synchronous=Off ";
            var Data = new data() { text = Text };
            using (var db = new SQLiteConnection("C:/data"))
            {
                db.Insert(Data);
            }
            return (Data);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Для примера попробуйте такой вариант с сохранением записи. Допустим, что при 0 id у нас записи не существует, а при 1 и выше у нас обновление существующих записей. По аналогии можете сделать метод с дополнительными, нужными вам условиями записи.

```
public int SaveItem (Data item) 
{
        using (var databaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection("C:/data"))
        {
            if (item.id > 0)
            {
                databaseConnection.Update(item);
                return item.id;
            }
            else
            {
                return databaseConnection.Insert(item);
            }               
        }
}
```